# Function in $L^\infty$ is element of $L^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mu$ positive measure and $f\in L^\infty(\mu)$.

My question is: $f\in L^2(\mu)$?

Thank you all.

Comment: yes if $\mu$ is finite (e.g. $L^{\infty}([0,1])\subseteq L^2([0,1]))$ but not in general.

Answer (score 5):

The costant functions are elements of $L^{\infty}$ in lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, but they're not $L^2$, unless they're not $0$.

It is true that a function $f\in L^{\infty}(\mu)$ is also in $L^2$ if the domain of the function has finite measure.

---

Answering your question: if $f\in L^{\infty}$ and $g\in L^2$, then 
$$\|fg\|_2^2=\int f^2g^2\le\|f\|_{\infty}^2\int g^2=\|f\|_{\infty}^2\|g\|_2^2$$

Comment: And for example, if $f\in L^\infty$ and $g\in L^2$ then $fg\in L^2$?

$\|fg\|_2\leq \|f\|_\infty \|g\|_2$? Thank you.

Comment: Yes, that's true

Comment: how to justify inequality?
I thought erroneously $\|f\|_2\leq \|f\|_\infty$.

Comment: In general for a space of finite measure $X$ we have the inequality $\|f\|_\infty \cdot \sqrt{\mu(X)} \geq \|f\|_2$, as if $\|f\|_\infty = c$ then $|f| \leq c$ almost everywhere so $|f|^2 \leq c^2$ so $\int |f|^2 \leq c^2 \mu(X)$ so the result follows.

Comment: Yes; But $fg\in L^2$? if $f\in L^\infty$  and $g\in L^2$?,if the measure of X not is necessarily finite.

Comment: @user126033: Use the fact that $|fg|\leq ||f||_{\infty}|g|$ to get that $|fg|^2 \leq ||f||_{\infty}^2|g|^2$, showing that $fg$ is indeed $L^2$.

Comment: @user126033 edited the post

Answer (score 2):

It depends.

If the domain has finite measure, then it is true; in general $p > q \implies \mathcal L ^p(\Omega) \subset \mathcal L ^ q(\Omega) $ if $|\Omega| < \infty$

Note that with the lebesgue measure, it means that $\Omega$ is finite, but it need not to be that way; for example if you use a probability measure (or every measure such that $\mu(\mathbb R) = L < \infty$) then the above implication is always true.

Answer (score 1):

This need not be true in general. For example, take $\mu$ to be the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$, and $f=\chi_{[0,\infty]}$. Then $f \in L^{\infty}$, but $f $ doesn't belong to $L^2$.

However, if $\mu$ is a finite measure, then any $L^{\infty}$ function is a $L^2$ function- this follows from the Caucy-Schwartz inequality.